# How to find convergence or divergence of a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I show that this is either convergent or divergent?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {5^n \over 4^n + 3}$

I think that it is a geometric series, and that I should reformat it so that it is in the form

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$

But it is the +3 in  the denominator of $4^n+3$ that is screwing me up, because I'm not sure how I would change the form now.

Comment: Hint: if a series converges, then its terms converge to zero. Is it the case here?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have to prove its conv/divergence using the integral test. So if I take the integral from 1 to infinity of that, it should equal D.N.E. or infinity I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a geometric series, but you have, as $n \to \infty$:
$$
{5^n \over 4^n + 3}=\left({5 \over 4}\right)^n \times\frac{1}{1+\frac3{4^n}} \sim \left({5 \over 4}\right)^n
$$ and by the comparison test you can conclude that **your initial series is divergent.**

Answer (score 2):

When you see the term of the series you know that $5^n$ is very larger then $4^n$ so the series is clearly divergent, to prove it may be you can show that $\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\geq 1$ for larger integer $n$ ($n\geq 2$ is sufficient) or you can also see that $4^{n-1}\leq 4^n+3$ hence:
$$\frac{5^n}{4^n+3}\geq 5\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{n-1} $$

and apply geometric series test.